# How can I disable caching via configuration in Yii?

Tags: php, caching, yii

In Yii, I have enabled APC caching through the config/main.php file:

```
'cache' => array(
    'class' => 'system.caching.CApcCache',
),
```

and it works just fine when I use Yii's built-in caching methods:

```
Yii::app()->cache->set('key', $value);
```

However, is there a way to temporarily turn this off based on configuration?  I don't want to have it enabled while `YII_DEBUG` is set to true, for example, and would like `$votes = Yii::app()->cache->get("key");` to *always* return false as it does when it's empty.

I've tried turning this off by just commenting-out the configuration setting, but it gives (not unreasonable) errors:  `Call to a member function get() on a non-object`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could configure a cache class that does not cache at all (so it won't store anything and `get()` will always return `FALSE`).

Probably Yii already ships with a no-cache? Yes it does, it's called `CDummyCache` and it does no caching at all.

It has been written for the problem you outline in your question that `Yii::app()->cache` is `NULL`.

See [*Caching*<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/caching.overview).

Answer (score 4):

If you need to disable cache only locally add the following code into main-local.php. It will override cache configuration in the main.php

```
'components' => [
... 
    'cache'=> [
        'class'=>'CDummyCache',
    ],
...
]
```

CDummyCache is a placeholder cache component.

CDummyCache does not cache anything. It is provided so that one can always configure a 'cache' application component and he does not need to check if Yii::app()->cache is null or not. By replacing CDummyCache with some other cache component, one can quickly switch from non-caching mode to caching mode.

[Yii 1.x: CDummyCache doc](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDummyCache)

[Yii 2.x: DummyCache doc](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-caching-dummycache.html)

Comment: This results in `Class CDummyCache does not exist`

Comment: If you use Yii 2.X in needs to use yii\caching\DummyCache vs CDummyCache

Answer (score -4):

Try this code:

```
'cache' => array(  
        'class' => 'system.caching.CFileCache'  
    ),
```

Comment: Please explain your answer in words, not just in code. And please explain how does your answer differ from the other answer, since the question was answered almost a year ago.

Comment: I wanted to *disable* caching, not change the caching mechanism. This would merely change how things were being cached.

Comment: This is just an example of how to configure Yii to cache to files. It doesn't answer the question. Flagged for deletion.